# How can one algorithmically define the required amount of centroids in K-Means clustering?

Tags: machine-learning, clustering

Say I have a dataset of n vectors. These are, by nature, clustered so that there is a significant distance difference between any two points within a cluster and any two points in separate clusters.

I want to create a single centroid per single cluster. However, I cannot initially know how many clusters there are - thus I cannot pre-define the k in K-means clustering.

What is the best way to define the k in K-Means, given the dense and clear clustering of the data?

Comment: See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10136470/unsupervised-clustering-with-unknown-number-of-clusters and https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/241381/clustering-methods-that-do-not-require-pre-specifying-the-number-of-clusters.